# Manipulation of the $6/49$ lottery

Tags: probability, combinations

If one manipulates the lottery $6/49$ by putting $6$ additional balls with the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ into the urn, what is the probability of the manipulation being busted on live-television? The probability of the manipulation being busted after the first two draws is $\frac{12}{55} \cdot \frac{1}{54}$ but what is the further approach?

Some help is much appreciated.

Comment: prob  a specific pair being picked, e.g. 1-1, then an exclusion/inclusion for 2 pairs, 3 pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{55}6$ total draws, and we need to count how many draws have two balls with the same number. This is best done with [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

There are $\binom{53}4$ ways to draw both $1$s (we have to choose the two $1$s and $4$ of the other $53$ balls), and the same number of ways to draw both $2$s, etc. Simply adding these up would count all the draws which have (say) both $1$s **and** both $2$s twice, so we need to subtract those.

There are $\binom{51}2$ draws which have both $1$s and both $2$s, and the same number for every other pair of choices from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Once we subtract all those off, we need to add the draws which have three pairs; there are $\binom63=20$ of these.

So the final answer is $$\frac{\binom61\binom{53}4-\binom62\binom{51}2+\binom63}{\binom{55}6}\approx 0.06.$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Will check out the inclusion-exclusion method and then rethink about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler argument (leading to a more complex formula) with the same result. Consider a set of 55 balls with two disjoint subsets of 6 balls each (both representing 1..6). The draws that do *not* show the manipulation can be described and computed like this:

for $a=0..6$ draw $a$ balls from $55-2*6=43$ and draw the remaining $6-a$ balls by taking $c \leq 6-a$ balls from the first 6-set and $6-a-c$ balls from the complement in the copy set.

In Maple this gives a probability of

evalf(add(binomial(43, a)*add(binomial(6, c)*binomial(6-c, 6-a-c), c = 0 .. 6-a), a = 0 .. 6))/binomial(55, 6)

giving 0.9400529671. The complement has indeed a probability of plm 0.06

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please explain what you mean by $55-2 \cdot 6 =43$? I don't understand it

Comment: There are $55$ balls, of which I subtract the two copies of $1..6$. From the remaining balls I  draw $a$ balls ($0 \le a \le 6$. I complete with drawing from the copies.